# malloc() 5GB memory on a 32 bit machine

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I was reading in a book:

> The virtual address space of a process on a 32 bit machine is 2^32 i.e. 4Gb of space. And every address seen in the program is a virtual address. The 4GB of space is further goes through user/kernel split 3-1GB.

To better understand this, I did malloc() of 5Gb space and tried to print the all addresses. If I print the addresses, How is the application going to print whole 5Gb address when It has only 3GB of virtual address space? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you *really* malloc all that memory? Could you paste up the relevant code?

Comment: if you use a 32 bit pointer, you can't address 5GB, so you also cannot print all addresses. It will wrap to zero.

Comment: Printing an address is completely unrelated to whether that address is available in any way. And Linux doesn't actually commit the allocated memory until you use it.

Comment: AFAIK, one process can not handle more than 4GB on 32bit OS/CPU even if you have more than 4GB RAM because of size_t length which is argument for malloc and handles max pointer size. So you have to create separate processes and allocate as much memory as you can, and handle this memory as shared.

Comment: That is a very good example that it make sense to switch of all compiler warnings or ignore them. Using a size_t argument and write the 5GB constant there should result in a warning ("integer overflow in expression" for gcc). But it is very interesting that you are able to use a pointer to run over 5GB on a 32bit system. Also a lot of warnings ignored? Hint: Read and understand compiler warnings!

Comment: There is vital information missing: did you `malloc` all memory at once (or - at least think you did)? In smaller chunks? Show the **minimal** code you used! And what does the compiler say? Warnings? Which did you have enabled? Why ignored?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`malloc()` takes `size_t` as an argument. On 32 bit system it's an alias to some unsigned 32 bit integer type. This means that you just cannot pass any value bigger than `2^32-1` as an argument for `malloc()` making it impossible request allocation of more than 4GB of memory using this function.

The same is true for all other functions that can be used to allocate memory. Ultimately they all end up as either `brk()` or `mmap` syscall. The length argument of `mmap()` is also of type `ssize_t` an in case of `brk()` you have to provide a pointer for the new end of your allocated space. The pointer is again 32 bit.

So there is absolutely no way to tell kernel you would like to get more than 4GB of memory allocated with one call) And it's not an accident - this just wouldn't make any sense anyway.

Now it's true that you could do several calls to malloc or other function that allocates memory, requesting more than 4GB in total. If you try this, the subsequent call (that would cause extending allocated memory to more than 3GB) will fail as there is just no address space available.

So I guess that you either didn't check the malloc return value or you did try to run code like this (or something similar):

```
int main() {
    assert(malloc(5*1<<30));
}
```

and assumed that you succeeded in allocating 5GB without verifying that your argument overflowed and instead of requesting 5368709120 bytes, you requested 1073741824. One example to verify this on Linux is to use:

`$ ltrace ./a.out
__libc_start_main(0x804844c, 1, 0xbfbcea74, 0x80484a0, 0x8048490 <unfinished ...>
malloc(1073741824) = 0x77746008
$`

Comment: `size_t` is an `unsigned long` (or `long unsigned int`) on 32bit systems, but it is also a 32bit data type.

Comment: "So there is absolutely no way to tell kernel you would like to get more than 4GB of memory allocated." nitpick: of course there is, just not in one chunk ;)

Comment: @mch: Well, actually this depends on the implementation. In gcc, for example, it's defined as `__SIZE_TYPE__` which in case of my compiler is actually "unsigned int"

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: It was a programming mistake actually. I thought that, malloc() succeeded for 5gb. And I was unhappy about this for a week. Thanks for a great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

There's already a good answer. Just in case, the size of your virtual address space is easily verifiable like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    size_t size = (size_t)-1L;
    void *foo;

    printf("trying to allocate %zu bytes\n", size);

    if (!(foo = malloc(size)))
    {
        perror("malloc()");
    }
    else
    {
        free(foo);
    }
}
```

> > gcc -m32 -omalloc malloc.c && ./malloc
>   trying to allocate 4294967295 bytes
>   malloc(): Cannot allocate memory

This must fail because parts of your address space are already occupied: by the mapped part of the kernel, by mapped shared libraries and by your program, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because there is no function for you to alloc 5GB memory.